# Using query to populate target data extension for resending automated mail

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, automation, sql

Every week we send out a mail on tuesdays.
This mail is named so it always contains this: "TOBERESENT".

Every saturday an automation sends out a mail that is an altered version of the tuesday mail. This mail is named so it always contains this: "THERESENDMAIL".

To keep this as automated as possible, I'd like queries, that on saturdays:

1) Populates a data extension (using overwrite) with everyone, who was sent the "TOBERESENT" mail. As a weekly mail is named like this, the mail to be found must not be more than a week old

2) Populates a data extension (using overwrite) with everyone, who opened the "TOBERESENT" mail. Again, the mail to be found must not be more than a week old

3) Subtracts 2) from 1) and this way populating (using overwrite) a third data extension with everyone, who did not open the tuesday mail.

Then when all queries are run, the automation will send the saturday mail to the third data extension, only targeting the ones who did not open the tuesday mail.

I'm quite sure I'll be able to set up every part of the automation, but I don't know much about queries. Can anyone help me write the SQL for these 3 queries?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will use the system data views to build your SQL.

SQL 1: Captures those who received an email ---> Populates DE: ResultingDE_fromSQL1
SELECT s.subscriberKey, j.jobid 
FROM [_job] j
JOIN [_Sent] s
ON s.jobid = j.jobid
AND s.EventDate > dateadd(d,-7,getdate())
AND j.EmailName like '%TobeResent%'

SQL 2: Captures those who have opened the email ---> Populates DE: ResultingDE_fromSQL2
SELECT s.subscriberKey 
FROM [ResultingDE_fromSQL1] j
JOIN [_Open] o
ON s.jobid = o.jobid
AND s.subscriberkey = o.subscriberKey
WHERE s.EventDate > dateadd(d,-7,getdate())
AND j.EmailName like '%TobeResent%'

SQL 3: Identifies the Non-Openers ---> Populates DE: ResultingDE_fromSQL3
SELECT s.subscriberKey
FROM [ResultingDE_fromSQL1] 
WHERE s.subscriberKey NOT IN (SELECT subscriberKey FROM [ResultingDE_fromSQL2])

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you!
Had to make small changes, but with these small changes it works like a charm, and I see it as my own free version of what Journey Builder offers. I'm grateful for your help and making this function not only saves me 30 minutes of work every week but also is a perfect introduction to SQL.

Comment: SELECT s.subscriberKey, j.jobid, sub.EmailAddress
FROM [_job] j 
JOIN [_Sent] s ON s.jobid = j.jobid AND s.EventDate > dateadd(d,-7,getdate()) AND j.EmailName like '%TOBERESENTDK%'
LEFT JOIN _Subscribers sub ON s.SubscriberKey = sub.SubscriberKey  
  
SELECT s.subscriberKey 
FROM [AutomatedRetargetStep1of3DK] s
JOIN [_Open] o ON s.jobid = o.jobid AND s.subscriberkey = o.subscriberKey  
  
SELECT s.subscriberKey, s.EmailAddress
FROM [AutomatedRetargetStep1of3DK] s
WHERE s.subscriberKey NOT IN (SELECT subscriberKey FROM [AutomatedRetargetStep2of3DK])